# Isekai manga about a thunder magician who dives into a dungeon and rescues an elf-like person

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic, isekai

It's an isekai manga about a thunder magician who dives into a dungeon. In the first chapter, he rescues an elf-like girl, who is a battle slave. The receptionist at the guild always tries to make a name for himself. He always dives solo. It is one horrendously big dungeon, so when they go on deep run they can be gone for days or weeks

He transferred to another world, then found a teacher who taught him thunder magic, but the manga begins after that. He's not a hero and not really a battle junkie. The fragment about the receptionist is just a little detail that I remembered. I think he was from our world, but not sure. I don't remember if he was transported or transferred into another person body but he wasn't a child.

It's not a colored manga.

Comment: So the thunder magician is already an established hero at the start, who always dives solo? Is it an actual diving action to enter the dungeon? And it's the receptionist at a guild he's a member of who is always trying to make a name for themselves? Given it's *isekai*, is he a person from our world? Was he transported or reincarnated? Do you remember anyone's hair color?

Comment: He transfered to another world, then found a teacher who taught him thunder magic, but manga begins after that. He`s not a hero and not really a battle junkie. Fragment about receptionist is just a little detail that i remembered. I think he was from our world, but not sure. I don`t remember if he was transported or transfered into another person body but he wasn`t a child. Manga wasn`t colored.

Comment: Those are good details to [edit] into your question. :) By the way, the odd formatting on your comment is because you used backticks instead of apostrophes, so the system tried to interpret them as fixed-width code.

Comment: And is "diving" into the dungeon just entering it? Or do they actually have to jump in headfirst?

Comment: Diving as entering, but it is one horrendously big dungeon, so when they go on deep run they can be gone for days or weeks

Comment: "diving" is the standard term for entering a loot/monster-filled dungeon. I'm sure there's an explanation for that. But it is not a literal dive, no.

Comment: @qazmlpok: Noted. I was kind of hoping it was some sort of unique detail that could be searched for.

Answer (score 1):

This is *[Houkago no Dungeon Diver: Nihon to Isekai wo Ikiki Dekiru You ni Natta Boku wa Level Up ni Isoshimimasu](https://myanimelist.net/manga/151251)*.

> Akira Kudo, a high school student who can freely travel back and forth between Japan and another world, Do Merta. With no goals in mind, he spends his time after school enjoying life in another world as he is!
>
> As an adventurer, he gets teased by the guild's receptionist, receives "rewards" from his magic master, and has fun with the girl he helped...!?
>
> "I hate pain! I don't care about ranking up! Guild requests are also troublesome!"
>
> A leisurely labyrinth exploration fantasy just for after school! (from [MU](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/0da0gq4))

The main character is a high schooler that can freely travel between his world and another. In the other world he works as a solo adventurer using lightning magic. He's friendly with a receptionist.

In chapter 1 he meets a battle slave elf whose master was just killed. He saves her life with his lightning magic, and helps her recover from her injuries, and finally breaks the slave magic that was on her.

[image: Banter with the receptionist] [image: Lightning magic in action]

Found by searching MU for the tags `Slave/s`, `Elf/ves`, and `Isekai`, filtered to Manga.